# Can't get mongoose 'populate' to work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am stuck on populating a ref field in a simple mongoose (3.8.8) query.
It's probably a stupid issue but i can't actually sort it out..

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ItemSchema = new Schema({
    description: { type: String },
    comments: [ { type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Comment'} ],
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

var Item = mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema);

var CommentSchema = new Schema({
    text: { type: String },
    item_id: { type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Item'} ,
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);

Item.find().populate('comments').exec(function(err,item){

    console.log('Item ',item)

})
```

the data is:

```
/* item0 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("53da00cc5ddd29442463e716"),
  "description" : "item1",
  "created" : ISODate("2014-07-31T08:39:40.475Z"),
  "comments" : [],
  "__v" : 0
}

/* item1 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("53da00cc5ddd29442463e717"),
  "description" : "item2",
  "created" : ISODate("2014-07-31T08:39:40.478Z"),
  "comments" : [],
  "__v" : 0
}



/* comment0 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("53da01e9ef4ecaa0231fdc8d"),
  "item_id" : ObjectId("53da00cc5ddd29442463e716"),
  "text" : "comment1",
  "created" : ISODate("2014-07-31T08:44:25.768Z"),
  "__v" : 0
}
```

It just won't work as expected, not populating the 'comments' array, tho in my comments collection the item_id is populated correctly.
What's the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the data look like? Odds are on that something is not right. So probably items in your comments array that do not match things in the comments collection. Usually due to not saving things correctly.

Comment: edited the post including the data

Comment: Your comments array is empty in every case? What are you expecting populate to do? It only "populates" or "pseudo joins" based on the `_id` values "pushed" into the array from the created comments. Clearly the actual problem is in the code where you "created" the comment and failed to do this.

Comment: well i was right then, it's actually a stupid issue. Thank you very much!